# ignite DBMS, how rename column

Tags: ignite

we have the ignite DBMS, the task is to rename the column, as far as I was able to find information ignite does not support renaming, what do you advise? I had an idea to add a new column, move the values from the old column to it after delete the old column, but the old column is included in the primaty key, I also could not find the information how to add the primaty key in ignite.
To make it clearer, have  is a table with columns column1, column2, column3, column4 where column1, column2 is the primary key, you need column2 to be called column_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially can't change the primary key columns in Ignite in an existing table. You could create a new table, move the data there, and drop the old one.